# Can anyone please explain what is the internal logic behind this code flow in java

Tags: java

Below is the simple program of inheritance.

```
Class Base {
  void fun() {
    System.out.println("fun");
  }
}

Class Sub extends Base{
  void fun () {
    System.out.println("In fun");
  }

  void display () {
    System.out.println ("Display");
  }
}

Base obj = new Sub ();
obj.fun();
obj.display();
```

In this case fun method of sub class is called , but display method is not called and a compilation error is happened.

Comment: Where is subclass/superclass? Where is display  method?

Comment: You don't extended the `Sub` class from `Base`. Kindly do it and try again,

Comment: Please, refer to the following explanation by Oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) as it provides more detailed explanation on how and why the inheritance works as this in Java. As is, this questions shows little motivation on your part to do some research before asking.

Comment: I think you did not get the question! I know the post has concepts of inheritance and run time polymorphism, but my concern to the fact how the object is being casted to the parent class, because we are creating the object of child class and storing the reference of object in the super class, so how it is excluding the methods of sub class.

Answer (score 0):

> The conecpt is called Dynamic method dispatch or Run time polymorphism.

According to this, you can store the `object (new ClassName();)` of derived class in `reference variable (BaseClass b)` of Base class.

But by doing this only the methods which are *either Base class's own methods will be called or the overridden methods in child class* will be called. By this method **child class's own methods** cannot be called.

That is why you get output of derived class's fun method and error on display method.

```
Base obj = new Sub();
obj.fun();               //-----------> In fun
obj.display();           //-----------> Error

obj = new Base();
obj.fun();               //-----------> fun
```

This is dynamic method dispatch.

Comment: Run time polymorphism  happened in the case of fun method but i want to know why the display method can not be called.

Comment: @Arijit.Ganguly Because that method belongs to the child class it self, Base class have no knowledge about its methods. So it cannot call any method of Child class it self.

Comment: @Arijit.Ganguly if you get the answer to your question, then you should accept an answer here by clicking on the Right tick mark on left side of answer.

Comment: If subclass object is created then how its method is hidden and as far as i know the upcasting never allocate new memory location then how the object of the subclass is manupulated

Comment: @Arijit.Ganguly However the object is of Derived class, but you are storing it in reference variable of Base class, and Base class only knows about its own methods, not about Child class's own methods.

Comment: what do you mean by storing ? the reference variable only points to the actual object.

Comment: @Arijit.Ganguly Yes that's what I meant, storing the reference to the object in reference variable.

Comment: reference means as per I know stored the Heap Memory location of the object in the reference variable. Then how could the actual derived class methods gone out from the object .